# Combined arrival rate

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, queueing-theory

Let us suppose a scenario with two clients, $a$ and $b$, each one generating load at rate $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$, respectively. The server receives the requests from both clients.

What will be the arrival rate at server?

(consider inter-arrival times *independently* generated by an exponential distribution)

Comment: The answer depends on whether the client request generation processes are _independent_ processes or _dependent_ processes. In the former case, the answer is $\lambda_a+\lambda_b$; in the latter, it is not.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, consider they are _independent_ processes. Could you give an example of why the answer, then, is the sum of the rates? (thank you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ denote the number of requests in $(0,T]$ from clients $a$ and $b$ relatively. Then, $A$ and $B$ are *Poisson* random variables with parameters $\lambda_aT$ and $\lambda_bT$ respectively, and you have
declared them to be independent random variables. Thus, $C = A+B$, the
total number of requests received during $(0,T]$ is a Poisson
random variable also with parameter $(\lambda_a+\lambda_b)T$. This is because for any $N \geq 0$,
\begin{align}
P\{C = N\} &= P\{A+B = N\}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^N P\{A= n, B = N-n\}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^N P\{A= n\}P\{B = N-n\}&{\scriptstyle{\text{because $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables}}}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^N \exp(-\lambda_aT)\frac{(\lambda_aT)^n}{n!}
\exp(-\lambda_bT)\frac{(\lambda_bT)^{N-n}}{(N-n)!}\\
&= \exp(-(\lambda_a+\lambda_b)T)\sum_{n=0}^N
\frac{(\lambda_aT)^n}{n!}\frac{(\lambda_bT)^{N-n}}{(N-n)!}\\
&= \frac{\exp(-(\lambda_a+\lambda_b)T)}{N!}
\sum_{n=0}^N \binom{N}{n}(\lambda_aT)^n(\lambda_bT)^{N-n}\\
&= \exp(-(\lambda_a+\lambda_b)T)\frac{((\lambda_a+\lambda_b)T)^N}{N!}
\end{align}
When $A$ and $B$ are not independent, this does not work because the
step above where independence was used is no longer valid.

Comment: Supposing $(0,T]$ is the time in which the samples happen, why let the _Poisson_ random variables' parameters be $\lambda_a T$ and $\lambda_b T$ instead of $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$?

Comment: $\lambda_a$ is the request _rate_, measured in number of requests per unit time. So, the average number of arrivals in $(0,T]$ is $\lambda_aT$, not just $\lambda_a$.

Comment: Yes, I got it. For instance, I also expand this question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169406/sum-of-two-independent-random-variables-application-inter-arrival-times/169495#169495). Could you comment there also? (thank you very much)

Comment: Considering the same proof you provided, the case of $\lambda_a = \lambda_b$ still valid, isn't it? (sorry for the naive confirmation)